# Using Ternary Operator to Throw Checked or Unchecked Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, ternary-operator

*My original question used `FileNotFoundException` and `IllegalStateException` and therefore they are included in the answer. I have changed them to their superclasses `IOException` and `RuntimeException` respectively for simplicity.*

---

This compiles (not using ternary, 1 checked, 1 unchecked):

```
private void test() throws IOException { // throws is required
    if (new Random().nextInt(2)==0) throw new IOException();
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

This also compiles (using ternary, 2 unchecked exceptions):

```
private void test3() { // throws not required
    throw new Random().nextInt(2)==0 ? new UncheckedIOException(null) : new RuntimeException();
}
```

But why does this not compile (using ternary, 1 checked, 1 unchecked)?

```
private void test2() throws IOException {
    throw new Random().nextInt(2)==0 ? new IOException() : new RuntimeException();
}
```

From Eclipse:

> Unhandled exception type Exception
>
> 2 quick fixes available:
>
> `J!` Add throws declaration
>
> `J!` Surround with try/catch

---

#### Another pair of examples

This compiles:

```
private void test4() { // throws not required
    if (new Random().nextInt(2)==0) throw new Error();
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

This does not:

```
private void test5() {
    throw new Random().nextInt(2)==0 ? new Error() : new RuntimeException();
}
```

From Eclipse:

> Unhandled exception type Throwable
>
> 2 quick fixes available:
>
> `J!` Add throws declaration
>
> `J!` Surround with try/catch

Comment: @NathanHughes the condition evaluates to `boolean `. The whole ternary expression does not need to evaluate to the same type, `System.out.println(a == b? "yes" : 5)` is fine.

Comment: @daniu that ternary expression is evalutated to `Object` which is the most common super-type

Comment: The key point is that the conditional operator is not a shorthand for an if statement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why does this not compile?

Because the inferred type of the conditional ?: operator in this case is `Exception`, following the rules of [JLS 15.25.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3). While the JLS gets complicated really quickly, the rules are trying to find "the most specific type where there's an implicit conversion from both of the operand types". A sort of "nearest common ancestor".

The inheritance hierarchy in this case is:

```
                      Exception
                   /              \
           IOException           RuntimeException
               /                         \
      FileNotFoundException           IllegalStateException
```

... so the nearest common ancestor is `Exception`. Your code is somewhat equivalent to:

```
private void test() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Exception exception = 1==0 ? new FileNotFoundException() : new IllegalStateException();
    throw exception;
}
```

Hopefully you already understand why *that* would fail to compile... in which case with any luck it's all clear now :)

Comment: If the common type was Throwable (one of the cases was Error or something) would it work?

Comment: @PaulStelian not unless you declared that `test() throws Throwable`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Throwable (Error etc) can be thrown without a throws declaration, hence my question stands. Only what is Exception and is not RuntimeException requires a throws declaration.

Comment: @AndyTurner @ Lino So actually it's a special case for the Error type that it's unchecked?

Comment: @PaulStelian yes. `Error` and `RuntimeException` (and subclasses) are unchecked; others are checked.

Comment: Indeed - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1